# Using a delegate for thread start inside another Sub

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

What I've got is something like this:

```
Private Sub GiantLegacySub()

... lots of variables and legacy code...

    Dim somethingNew = New Func(of String, Boolean)(
        Function(stringy as String) As Boolean
            ... new code that uses the legacy variables ...
        End Function)

    Dim t = New Thread(AddressOf somethingNew)

End Sub
```

I am getting an error indicating that `somethingNew` is being seen as variable name and not a method name and is thus unacceptable by `AddressOf`.  ( I know that `somethingNew` is a variable, just one that happens to contain a pointer to a method).

Is there a way to do this?  I need to leave it inside of `GiantLegacySub` because of the shear volume of variables in its scope.

Comment: `AddressOf` is used to convert a routine into a delegate.  In this case, though, you already have a delegate, because you declared `somethingNew` as one.  You should be able to provide `somethingNew` directly without `AddressOf`.  The only issue would be making sure it matches the required signature---note that if you have `Option Strict Off` VB will try to be helpful and can make slightly mismatched delegates line up.

Comment: Note that `System.Thread` takes a `Sub` rather than a `Function` as the parameter (either with no parameters, or with a single `Object` parameter), so you should modify your declaration accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Craig's guidance, this was the answer:

```
Private Sub GiantLegacySub()

... lots of variables and legacy code...

    Dim somethingNew = Sub(stringy as String)
            ... new code that uses the legacy variables ...
        End Sub

    Dim t = New Thread(somethingNew)
    t.Start(someStringForStringy)

End Sub
```